# Orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\{w_1,w_2,...,w_k\}$ be a basis for a subspace $W$ of $V$. Show that $W^⊥$ consists of all vectors in V that are orthogonal to every basis vector.

I know that the intersection of the two subspaces is a set containing only the zero vector.

the set is a basis so it's linearly independent but it's not orthogonal because then the intersection would have more than just the zero vector. and if the set is a basis for the subspace $W$ then it is also the $col(W)$ and I know that the orthogonal complement of $col(W)$ would be $null(W^T)$ This is where I am stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go back to the definitions.

Let $S$ be the set of all vectors that are orthogonal to every basis vector.
We need to show two things:

- if $x \in W^\perp$, then $x \in S$
- if $x \in S$, then $x \in W^\perp$

After proving that, we could say that $W^\perp \subseteq S$ and $S \subseteq W^\perp$, so that $W^\perp = S,$ which is what we're trying to show.

Proving the first statement is relatively easy, and uses only the definition of $W^\perp$.  Proving the second statement requires that you use the definition of a basis and go through some algebra.

Remember that $x$ is orthogonal to $w$ *means* $\langle w,x \rangle = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

1)Assume $x \in W^{\bot}$ then $<x,w_i>=0$ where $w_i \in W, i=1,...,k$ thus $x \in S$ and $W^{\bot} \subseteq S$

2) suppose $x \in S$.  Consider any $w \in W$.  We may write $w = c_1w_1 + \cdots + c_k w_k$.  It follows that
$$
\langle x,w_i \rangle=0 \quad \text{for }i = 1,\dots,k \implies \\ 
c_1\langle x,w_1 \rangle + \cdots + c_k\langle x,w_k\rangle =0 \implies\\
\langle x, c_1w_1+c_2w_2+...+c_kw_k \rangle =0 \implies \\
\langle x,w \rangle = 0
$$
thus $x \in W^{\bot}$ and $W^{\bot} \subseteq S$

Therefore $W^{\bot} = S$

Comment: Your proof looks great, well done!  LaTeX note: you should use `\langle` and `\rangle` for brackets like these $\langle \rangle$ rather than $<>$.  Also, I find that the `\implies` arrow ($\implies$) looks nicer than $\Rightarrow$.

Comment: There are also some parts of the proof that you should elaborate on, even if you do have the broad strokes.

Comment: will do! thanks!